# Markdown in chat fails sometimes for single line messages too

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, markdown

I found many questions similar to chat formatting issues but unfortunately none of them addresses my issue related to chat formatting and I am making it clear that I am *not* talking about multiline messages.

So personally I observed it mostly for formatting of code and italics, they  just don't work *always*. What I have seen is for italics: *sometimes* *text* don't work but _text_ work in a single line message and vice-versa and same for code formatting: backticks don't work but `Ctrl+k` works *always*. I discussed this issue in [Chat feedback](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2/chat-feedback) too, but unfortunately, no solution came up therefore here I am providing some chat links realted to these issues:-

For code formatting: [1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47372807#47372807) (line 2), [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48268238#48268238) (line 4)

For italicised text [1](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47664041#47664041) (line 2),  [2](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51085788#51085788) (line 3), [3](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48271363#48271363) (line 3)

At first I thought, It is not formatting just for me but I had asked my fellow users in chat room, they have experienced it too.

PS: In no way I am saying that chat formatting just never works but It is also true that It don't work *always* (Only SE Devs can tell why)

Comment: I think that is [tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: @BlackThunder Here I am talking about _single line_ messages only

Comment: Talking about single lines, its [tag:status-norepro]. Can you meet me in this sandbox?  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1/sandbox

Comment: Your examples are all multi line messages.

Comment: @ShaWiz No, that's why I mentioned the line no. in each example

Comment: I really don't understand. You know there are few lines. So that is multi line. So you simply don't understand the meaning of this term?

Comment: Yep, I _misunderstood_ the term

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of your examples contain newlines. This makes them multi-line messages. Chat does not currently support rendering markdown in multiline messages.

Comment: This  https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48268523#48268523 contains multiline too but it is formatted nicely. Why?

Comment: That message contains no newlines; it *wraps* to multiple lines, but only by necessity - if you had a wide enough screen, it would show up on a single line.

Comment: Oh God! I misunderstood what a "multiline" message means, you are right. Now I understand why my messages were not get formatted.